# C compile error not making sense

Tags: c

I have been dealing with an error for a while now and was looking to get some help/clarity.
The error when I compile reads as follows"

Demo1.c:179:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]

The line that the error refers to is:

```
printf("Phone No:%d\n",s.phone_no);
```

Comment: It's `*s.phone_no` maybe.

Comment: s.phone_no is a pointer to an integer. %d expects an integer. As Kerrek suggests above, to get an integer from a pointer to an integer, dereference with a *.

Comment: @thang obviously he/she is learning no need to be that way

Comment: try *s.phone_no or s->phone_no

Comment: @camelccc `*s.phone_no` and `s->phone_no` are *very* different, and you would do well to understand that difference before giving people rude advice about c pointers.

Answer (score 1):

s.phone_no is a pointer to an integer, and the %d is expecting an integer.

use

```
*(s.phone_no)
```

instead of

```
s.phone_no
```

in the printf.  That ought to take care of your issue.